# Algorithm for Tiling Rectangle with a Family of Squares

Tags: general-topology, rectangles, tiling

I'm reading a paper on tiling open bounded regions in $\mathbb{R}^2$, and I'm not quite sure about this example of tiling a rectangle with a family of squares, where each square touches a specific portion of the boundary of the rectangle. The algorithm presented is something akin to Euclid's algorithm for finding a greatest common divisor, except in this case, the lengths of the sides can be any positive real numbers, not just natural numbers. In particular, I'm confused by the second case the author presents, where ${Q_k}$ is an infinite set. How do we know this tiling covers *all of* the interior of the rectangle?

Thanks.

The paper is *Tiling Bounded Open Sets with Squares that Touch the Boundary* by William T. Trotter.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$S_n$ is the part of the interior not covered by the squares 
$\{ Q_k \mid k < n \}$ and it is always an open rectangle, where one
of the corners is $(b,d)$.

We know that $\displaystyle\lim_{k \to \infty} \lambda(Q_k) = 0$, since 
$\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^\infty \lambda(Q_k) \le (b-a)(d-c)$. Whenever $\lambda(Q_k) < \lambda(Q_{k-1})$ it must also be the case that 
$\lambda(S_k) < \lambda(Q_{k-1})$. It follows that there is a subsequence
$\{S_{n_k}\}$ with area converging to 0. This implies that $\displaystyle\bigcap_{k\ge 0} S_{n_k} = \emptyset$.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. So if I'm following correctly, this is what you are saying: the tiles $Q_k$ must decrease to zero area, since the sum of their areas cannot exceed the original rectangle. Next, you say that when the next tile is smaller than the previous, that must also mean the remainder S must be smaller than the previous tile. And this shrinking of the tiles must occur infinitely often, and since the tiles approach zero in area, this means the means the remainder $S_k$ must also go to zero, so that their intersection is null. Correct?

Comment: Yes, that is it.